# Paleta de cores (VBA/Excel), evento "botão direito do mouse" para objetos Frame

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Não encontrei referência sobre o evento que seja acionado pelo botão direito do mouse em um objeto Frame. Com o evento do botão esquerdo do mouse seleciono a cor desejada, isto está funcionando, porém, com o botão direito eu definiria as cores personalizadas dinamicamente, mas não encontrei o evento desejado para fazer isso.

A ideia é alterar a cor de fundo de cores a serem personalizadas (já funciona também) ao clicar o botão direito em um objeto Frame. Cada frame representa uma cor adicional a personalizar (são as dezesseis áreas em branco da parte inferior da paleta).

[image: Paleta de cores]

Existe evento correspondente ao clicar do botão direito do mouse para o objeto Frame?

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Veja a solução encontrada na Resposta abaixo

Comment: Mostra a tela onde você está programando. Mostra um print

Comment: Oi Eduardo, não entendi. Esta paleta já é um PrintScreen editado que coloquei em um objeto imagem. Pelo mouse move (x,y), sei a região que o cursor está, e com o click qual a cor que foi selecionada. O que quero é, da mesma forma, ao clicar o botão direito do mouse em cima de um dos dezesseis frames em branco, abrir outra imagem que tenho que usa o RGB conforme as coordenadas x e y (mostrando várias cores dinamicamente) e ao clicar, ele retorna a cor escolhida (isso já funciona). Portanto, Resta apenas eu aplicar o evento que acione o botão direito do mouse. É isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUÇÃO**

Encontrei o modo de fazer o controle do clicar do botão direito do mouse sob um *frame* (serve para outros objetos também).

Deve-se usar o evento *MouseDown* ou *MouseUp*, por exemplo (após criar o *Frame1* no formulário):

```
Private Sub Frame1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

If Button = 2 Then MsgBox "Botão direito do mouse"

End Sub
```

Neste *link* aparece os valores correspondentes a cada botão do mouse, e a soma pode ser combinada para saber se mais de um foi acionado ao mesmo tempo:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/gg278486.aspx

Um detalhe, veja o nome dos parâmetros criados dentro do evento que for manipular (olhe os argumentos do evento), pois há diferenças do que está informado no *site*, uma vez que a descrição é para eventos de formulário (fm), por exemplo, a variável *fmButton* é indicada para capturar o valor do botão acionado do mouse em um formulário, mas no evento do frame a variável é simplesmente *Button*.

É isso!